# onreadystatechange event with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to use the `onreadystatechange` event from the (underlying) `XMLHttpRequest` of JQuery's (2.0.2) `$.ajax(...)` to fire synchronous ajax requests so I can show an accurate status indication to the end user for long running requests. But it seems this functionality has been removed from the latest version of JQuery (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4107909/424963)), making spinners with asynchronous web requests the *only* option for representing the activity to the user.

using `XMLHttpRequest` I would do something like the following (though I still wan't to use JQuery), is there still a way in JQuery to gain access to a readystate change function? Is there perhaps a plugin that exposes the `onreadystatechange` event?

```
function pad(width, string, padding) { // from stackoverflow.com/a/15660515/424963 
  return (width <= string.length) ? string : pad(width, string + padding, padding)
}

$(function(){
    $("<div>Loading</div>").appendTo($("body"));
    var anticache = "?anticache=" + new Date().getTime();

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4){
            $("div").html("Done");
        }
        else  {
            $("div").html("Loading" + pad(xhr.readyState, "", "."));
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "jsfiddle.net" + anticache, true );
    xhr.send();    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5pqM/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you mean something like this:

```
var _orgAjax = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
    var xhr = _orgAjax();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //you can log xhr.readystate here
        if( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
             $("div").html("Done");
        }
    }
    return xhr;
};
$(function(){
    $("<div>Loading</div>").appendTo($("body"));
    var anticache = "?anticache=" + new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net",
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MmQ95/)

Comment: I looked for this for the longest time! However, is it possible to get this to work with jQuery 1.11.0? It seems like it's not working there.